# Getting error while firing an event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

i Have created one event-:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:attribute name="comp" type="Object"/>
</aura:event>
```

One application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" access="GLOBAL" useAppcache="true">
<aura:attribute name="components" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="ShowComponent" type="Boolean" default="True"/>
<aura:handler name="compEvent" event="c:WM_Navigation" action="{!c.eventHandler}"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ShowComponent}">
    <c:EventFirstComponent />
        </aura:if>

    <div class="slds"> 
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-1"> 
           <div class="slds">        
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.components}" var="cmp">
                    {!cmp}
                </aura:iteration>

            </div>  

            </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

---

Controller

```
({
    eventHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
    var obj = event.getParam('comp');
        console.log('event in app builder:'+JSON.stringify(obj));        
        var componentsToBeCreated = [];
        componentsToBeCreated.push(obj);
        alert(componentsToBeCreated);
        $A.createComponents(
            componentsToBeCreated,
            function(createdComponents, status,errorMessage){
                alert('status'+status);
                if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
                    component.set("v.components", createdComponents);
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") 
                {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
                }
                    else if (status === "ERROR") 
                    {
                        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
                    }



            });
    },
})
```

---

first component

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:registerEvent name="compEvent" type="c:WM_Navigation"/>
   Hello Welcome to Event Component.
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

---

Controller

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
       var compEvt = component.getEvent("compEvent");

       // compEvt.setParams({"comp":["c:EventSecondComponent"]});
       alert('Enent fi');
        compEvt.setParams({"comp":["c:EventSecondComponent" ,{}] }) ;
        alert('Enent else');
        compEvt.fire();

    }
})
```

when i am firing this event i am getting this error

> Error: [{"status":"ERROR","message":"An internal server error has
>   occurred\nError ID: 41061075-30796 (-488974888)"}]

Answer (score 0):

1. did you registerEvent on the sending child component
2. do you have event handler on the parent component 
   you cant fire component in the .setParams only attribute, it should look something like this

   ```
    var myEvent = component.getEvent("EventName");
    myEvent.setParams({ attributeName: attributeName });
    myEvent.fire();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your `EventFirstComponent` controller you are passing `c:EventSecondComponent` as parameter. So you are passing a Component as the parameter to be added dynamically in the application.

```
compEvt.setParams({"comp":["c:EventSecondComponent" ,{}] }) ;
```

Please check whether **EventSecondComponent** is already present in the Org. If not then you have to create it. It will solve the *internal server error*.